# Issue to add a column to document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When adding a column to a document library, I get the following error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details view of
>   the application error.
>
> Details: To enable the display the details of this specific error
>   message on the local server, create a  tag in a
>   configuration file "web.config" in the root of the web application
>   directory. Then assign the "RemoteOnly" value attribute "mode" of this
>   tag . To enable the display of information on remote
>   computers, set the "Off" to the attribute "mode"

Comment: You should look in the ULS logs for the real error message (the above gives no clue)

Comment: where i could find it

Comment: Standard they are in the 14 or 15-hive, in a Logs folder: http://samirvaidya.blogspot.se/2012/03/where-are-sharepoint-uls-logs.html but technically you could have configured to put them in another location as part of your install or a config